# purrr::map_if: apply a function only to specific columns

Tags: r, purrr

Until now, when I wanted to apply a function to, say, numeric columns only, I used

```
library(tidyverse)

map(diamonds[map_lgl(diamonds, is.numeric)], range, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now I am wondering if this is a situation where `map_if()` would be less clunky. What I tried is this:

```
map_if(diamonds, is.numeric, range, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But for some reason, the `range` is now calculated for all columns, not only numeric ones.

Am I doing something wrong or do I misunderstand the purpose of `map_if()`? If the latter, what is a situtation in which I would use `map_if()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `summarise_if`

```
diamonds %>% 
     summarise_if(is.numeric, funs(list(range(.)))) %>%
     unnest
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   carat depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.200  43.0  43.0   326   0     0     0  
#2 5.01   79.0  95.0 18823  10.7  58.9  31.8
```

---

The `map_if` will apply on the function on the `numeric` columns and untouch the other columns so that we get the original values from those columns.  The `summarise_if` will subset the dataset based on the condition and apply the function on those columns

Answer (score -1):

I just ran your code in mine and it works fine:

```
map_if( diamonds, is.numeric, range, na.rm = TRUE)
$carat
[1] 0.20 5.01

$cut
   [1] Ideal     Premium   Good      Premium   Good      Very Good Very Good     Very Good Fair      Very Good Good      Ideal     Premium  
  [14] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Good      Good      Very Good Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good
  [27] Premium   Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Good      Good      Good      Very Good
  [40] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Good      Good      Good      Premium   Very Good Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal    
  [53] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Very Good Good      Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium  
  [66] Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Premium   Premium   Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good
  [79] Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal    
  [92] Fair      Ideal     Very Good Very Good Good      Good      Fair      Very Good Premium   Very Good Premium   Ideal     Premium  
 [105] Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Premium  
 [118] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Fair      Fair      Premium   Premium   Very Good Fair      Fair     
 [131] Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Very Good Very Good Premium   Very Good Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium   Very Good
 [144] Very Good Ideal     Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Premium   Premium   Very Good Ideal    
 [157] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal    
 [170] Good      Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Good      Very Good Very Good Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal    
 [183] Ideal     Ideal     Good      Ideal     Very Good Premium   Very Good Good      Good      Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium  
 [196] Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Premium   Premium   Good      Fair      Premium   Very Good Ideal    
 [209] Very Good Ideal     Very Good Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal    
 [222] Good      Premium   Very Good Ideal     Premium   Premium   Fair      Premium   Ideal     Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal    
 [235] Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Good      Good      Ideal     Fair      Premium   Good      Good      Premium   Premium  
 [248] Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Fair      Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Premium  
 [261] Premium   Very Good Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Very Good Very Good Good     
 [274] Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Premium   Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Good     
 [287] Very Good Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Premium   Fair     
 [300] Very Good Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Good      Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium  
 [313] Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Premium   Good      Good      Premium   Premium   Premium  
 [326] Very Good Ideal     Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium  
 [339] Premium   Premium   Very Good Ideal     Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal    
 [352] Ideal     Fair      Premium   Premium   Ideal     Fair      Premium   Ideal     Fair      Good      Very Good Very Good Ideal    
 [365] Very Good Very Good Premium   Very Good Very Good Fair      Very Good Ideal     Very Good Very Good Premium   Premium   Fair     
 [378] Very Good Very Good Ideal     Good      Good      Very Good Very Good Fair      Fair      Very Good Very Good Good      Very Good
 [391] Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Good      Ideal     Very Good
 [404] Good      Ideal     Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Very Good
 [417] Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Fair      Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Good     
 [430] Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Very Good Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Fair      Premium  
 [443] Premium   Fair      Premium   Very Good Ideal     Good      Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium  
 [456] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal    
 [469] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Fair      Very Good Ideal     Good      Good      Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal    
 [482] Premium   Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal    
 [495] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Good      Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Good      Ideal     Ideal    
 [508] Premium   Premium   Ideal     Very Good Good      Premium   Ideal     Fair      Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Good      Ideal    
 [521] Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Premium   Premium   Fair      Premium   Good      Premium   Premium   Very Good Premium  
 [534] Very Good Premium   Ideal     Very Good Good      Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium   Good      Ideal    
 [547] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal    
 [560] Premium   Ideal     Very Good Very Good Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal    
 [573] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Fair      Ideal     Ideal     Ideal    
 [586] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Good      Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Fair      Premium   Premium  
 [599] Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium  
 [612] Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Premium  
 [625] Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Premium   Fair      Ideal    
 [638] Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Ideal    
 [651] Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Good      Ideal     Very Good Very Good Good      Premium   Ideal     Very Good Ideal    
 [664] Fair      Good      Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal    
 [677] Fair      Good      Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Very Good Premium   Ideal     Very Good
 [690] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium   Good      Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good Premium  
 [703] Premium   Fair      Fair      Good      Fair      Premium   Premium   Very Good Good      Premium   Fair      Fair      Fair     
 [716] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Good      Good      Good      Good      Very Good
 [729] Ideal     Good      Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium  
 [742] Premium   Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Fair      Premium   Premium   Good     
 [755] Very Good Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Very Good Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Very Good Premium   Ideal    
 [768] Ideal     Premium   Good      Fair      Fair      Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Fair      Premium   Very Good
 [781] Very Good Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Fair      Premium   Premium   Very Good Very Good
 [794] Very Good Premium   Very Good Ideal     Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Fair      Premium   Good      Ideal     Premium  
 [807] Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Premium  
 [820] Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium   Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Premium  
 [833] Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Fair      Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Premium  
 [846] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium  
 [859] Very Good Good      Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Good      Very Good Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Good      Ideal     Ideal    
 [872] Very Good Very Good Ideal     Good      Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Fair      Premium   Good      Fair     
 [885] Fair      Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Fair      Ideal    
 [898] Fair      Fair      Fair      Premium   Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Good      Good      Very Good Very Good Very Good
 [911] Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium   Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Fair      Ideal     Very Good Very Good
 [924] Ideal     Very Good Premium   Very Good Ideal     Premium   Fair      Premium   Ideal     Good      Fair      Fair      Very Good
 [937] Premium   Ideal     Fair      Fair      Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Premium   Ideal     Very Good Very Good Very Good Good     
 [950] Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Good      Ideal     Very Good Ideal    
 [963] Ideal     Ideal     Ideal     Good      Ideal     Fair      Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Ideal     Good     
 [976] Very Good Premium   Very Good Ideal     Ideal     Very Good Very Good Ideal     Very Good Very Good Very Good Ideal     Ideal    
 [989] Ideal     Ideal     Premium   Very Good Ideal     Very Good Premium   Ideal     Ideal     Good      Premium   Premium  
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 52940 entries ]
Levels: Fair < Good < Very Good < Premium < Ideal

$color
   [1] E E E I J J I H E H J J F J E E I J J J I E H J J G I J D F F F E E D F E H D I I J D D H F H H E H F G I E D I J I I I I D D D I G
  [67] I G G E D H H H H F E D D E E D E I E G H H H I E E G E G E F F E H D E G G I G G I F E F E I G F F F G E F D E F F F F H D H H H D
 [133] D E H E F F H G G G D F D H G D D E D I D G F D F G G D G H F G F H F G F E D D J E E I F G E E E E G G G G D F F F F E E E E E E E
 [199] E F E E E E H F E F H E F G F G G F H H H D G E E D D D D G F F F H F F D H I I D G F E H F E E E J G E G G E E H J G I F F F I E E
 [265] E E F F H F G E E I H E E I F F D I H G I E H E D D D F D G H H G F E H I E F D G I E I G G H G I G G F F F H F F F F G J G F E F F
 [331] E G E G F F G G G G G D E E E D F F H D D D I F F E E F G F G G H F F F J H F G G E D F D F F F F D F G F D J I G F E F I I I I I I
 [397] H H H H H H H I H E E F H H I I G F G E F I G E F F D J E F G E I E E E D F G H H H H J F H E E G I G D F H H E I E E F E E E E J E
 [463] E E E H F H E E F E H G H F F G E E E E E E E D E E E E E E F I F D D D D J D E E D E D D E F D D I E E H E D I E F E G H G H J H E
 [529] E I E D E I F F D D H H H D H F E E F E E E H F F F I G E E E E G F I G G H F J I E D D F H F G H D F I J G E F F E E E F H E E E F
 [595] H F F F F G F E F F G E F F F F F F F G E G G F G F H F F F D F H F D D F F F F F G D F G I F E E E F D G F E F G E E I I H E E H H
 [661] D F H H H E E F E G G H E D G D D E E E F J H F D F H F E I G E I F G D D E I H E H E J J J H E F F J D E I G H F G F I E E H G E E
 [727] E G E E I I I I I I G H H G F G G F J J J I I I H F F E G E I E G F F E E E E J E D D E G D D D F G D F E F J E D F D G G I F E D D
 [793] F D F F H E H E E E E I D G F D D D D D D J J H E F E E E I D D D E H I H D H H F F F F F F G F I G E E D E G G H F E E G H F H E I
 [859] E E J I G D D I G D E D D D E E G F E E I H I J J I I J F D F F G F F F G H H J I H E E H E G H F F F D I F F E F F G G J F F J D H
 [925] E H H F F F F D H H I F I D E D E E D E I G E F H F E E F F E F F F F G E F E E D D H H F G G F H G G G G E G F G F G G G G F D E D
 [991] E I I D E D E F D J
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 52940 entries ]
Levels: D < E < F < G < H < I < J

$clarity
   [1] SI2  SI1  VS1  VS2  SI2  VVS2 VVS1 SI1  VS2  VS1  SI1  VS1  SI1  SI2  SI2  I1   SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  VS2  VS1  SI1  SI1  VVS2
  [27] VS1  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  SI1  VS2  SI2  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS1  SI2  SI1  SI2  SI2  VS2  SI2  SI1  VS1 
  [53] SI1  VS2  VS2  SI2  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  VVS2 VVS1 SI1  SI1  VVS1 VVS1 SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VVS2 VVS2 VVS2
  [79] VVS2 VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS2 SI2  VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS2 SI1  SI1  SI2  VS2  VS2  SI2  VS2  VS1  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2 
 [105] VS1  SI1  SI1  VVS2 SI2  VVS2 SI2  SI2  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  SI2  VS2  VS2  SI2  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  VVS2 SI2  SI2 
 [131] VS2  SI1  SI1  VS2  VS1  VVS1 VS1  VS1  SI1  VVS1 VS2  VS2  VS2  VS1  SI2  VVS2 VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI2 
 [157] SI1  VS2  VS1  SI2  VS2  VVS2 SI1  VS2  SI2  VVS1 SI2  VVS1 VVS1 VS2  SI2  VS2  I1   VS1  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VVS2 VVS2
 [183] SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI2  SI1  SI1  VVS1
 [209] VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS1  I1   SI1  SI1  VS1  VVS2 VS2  VS1  VS1  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  IF   VS2  VS1  VS2  VVS1
 [235] VS1  VVS1 VS1  VVS2 VS2  VS1  SI1  I1   SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  SI2  SI1  IF   SI2  VVS2 VVS1 VS1  SI2  IF   VVS1 SI2  VS1 
 [261] VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1  VS1  VVS2 VS1  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  VS2  VVS2 SI2  VS1  SI2  IF   VS2  VS2  SI2  SI1 
 [287] SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VVS2 VVS1 VS2  VS1  VS1  VVS1 SI2  SI2  VS2  VS1  SI2  SI2  SI1  IF   SI2  VS1  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1 
 [313] VS1  IF   VS1  I1   VS2  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  I1   SI2  SI2  IF   VS2  VS1  VS2  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS1  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS2 
 [339] VS2  VS2  VS1  SI2  VS2  VS2  SI2  SI1  VS1  VS1  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VS2  SI2  VVS1 VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  VVS1 SI1 
 [365] VS1  VS1  SI2  VS2  VS1  I1   VS2  VVS2 SI1  SI1  SI2  SI1  I1   VS1  VS1  SI2  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI2  VS1  VS2  SI1  VS2 
 [391] SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  VS1  VS1  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  SI1  I1  
 [417] VS2  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI1  VS2  VVS1 SI2  SI1  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VVS1 SI2  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI2  SI2 
 [443] VS2  SI2  I1   VVS2 VVS2 VS1  SI1  SI2  SI1  SI1  VVS2 VS2  VS2  VVS2 SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  I1   SI2  SI1 
 [469] VS1  VS1  VS2  VS1  SI2  VS1  VS1  VS1  SI2  VS1  SI1  VS2  VVS1 SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VVS2 VVS1
 [495] SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI2  SI1  VS2  VVS2 SI2  SI1  VS2  VVS2 VS1  SI2 
 [521] SI2  VS1  SI1  VS1  SI1  I1   SI2  VS1  VS1  SI2  VS1  VS2  VS1  SI2  SI1  I1   SI1  VS2  VVS2 VVS1 VVS1 SI2  SI2  VS1  SI2  VVS1
 [547] VS1  SI2  SI2  VS2  SI1  I1   VVS1 VVS1 VS2  SI1  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI2  VVS2 SI1  SI1  VS1  SI1  VS2  IF   VS2  VS2 
 [573] VVS2 SI2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VVS1 VVS1 VS2  SI1  SI2  SI2  VS1  VVS2 VS2  VS2  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS1  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1  VS2 
 [599] VS2  VS1  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS1  SI1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS1  VS2  VS2  VS1  VVS2 VS1  VS2  VS1  VS1  SI2  SI1  VS2 
 [625] SI2  SI2  VVS1 VS2  VS1  SI1  SI2  SI2  SI2  VVS1 I1   SI1  SI1  VS2  VS1  VS1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI2  SI1  VVS2 VS1  VS2  SI2 
 [651] VVS2 SI1  VS1  I1   I1   VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI2  SI1  VS1  VVS2 SI2  I1   SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  VS2  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VVS2 VVS2
 [677] SI2  SI1  VS1  VS2  VS2  SI1  I1   SI1  VS1  SI2  SI1  SI1  IF   VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VS1  SI2  SI2  SI1  VS1  VS1  VS1  I1  
 [703] VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  VS1  VVS2 VS2  SI1  VS2  SI2  SI1  SI2  SI2  VVS2 SI2  I1   SI1  VS1  VS1  SI1  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2 
 [729] SI1  VS2  VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VVS1 VS2  VS1  VS1  SI2  SI2  SI2  SI2  SI2  VS1  VS1  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI2  SI1  SI1  VVS2
 [755] SI2  SI1  VS2  SI1  VVS2 SI1  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VVS2 SI2  VS2  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS1  VS2  VS1  SI2  VS2 
 [781] SI2  VVS2 VS1  VVS1 SI1  VVS2 VVS2 SI1  IF   SI2  VS1  SI1  SI1  SI2  SI1  VVS1 VS2  VS2  VS1  VS2  I1   SI2  VS2  VS2  SI1  SI1 
 [807] SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VVS2 SI1  VS2  SI1  VS2  SI2  VS2  SI1  VVS1 VVS1 VS1  VVS1 SI1  VVS1 VS2  VVS1 VS2 
 [833] SI2  SI2  VVS1 SI2  SI2  SI2  SI1  SI2  VS1  IF   SI2  SI1  I1   SI1  IF   VVS2 VVS2 VVS2 SI2  VVS2 SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  VS1  I1  
 [859] SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  I1   SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  SI1  VS2  SI1  SI2  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1 
 [885] SI1  SI1  VS2  VS2  VS1  VS1  VVS2 VS1  VS1  VS1  VVS2 SI2  SI1  VS1  SI1  SI2  VS1  VS2  VS1  VS1  VS2  VVS1 VS1  SI1  SI1  SI2 
 [911] VS2  SI1  SI1  IF   VS1  VS1  SI2  SI2  SI2  VS1  VS1  SI2  SI1  VVS1 VS2  I1   IF   VVS1 VS2  SI1  VS2  SI1  SI2  SI2  SI2  SI1 
 [937] SI1  SI2  SI1  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI1  VS1  VS1  VVS2 VS2  VS1  SI2  VS1  VVS2 VVS2 SI1  VS2  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  SI1  VVS1 VS2  VS2 
 [963] VS2  VS2  SI1  VS2  SI2  I1   VS1  SI2  VVS2 VS2  VVS1 SI2  SI2  SI1  SI1  SI2  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS1  VVS2 VS1  VS2  VS2  VVS1 SI1 
 [989] SI2  SI2  SI1  I1   I1   VVS2 SI1  VVS2 SI1  VS1  VS2  SI2 
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 52940 entries ]
Levels: I1 < SI2 < SI1 < VS2 < VS1 < VVS2 < VVS1 < IF

$depth
[1] 43 79

$table
[1] 43 95

$price
[1]   326 18823

$x
[1]  0.00 10.74

$y
[1]  0.0 58.9

$z
[1]  0.0 31.8
```

I'd suggest upgrading R as well as the packages you're using to the latest version. If that doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I want to apply the `range` function to numeric variables only. `cut` for example, is a factor.